# React - Predicate functional component

Tags: reactjs, jsx, conditional-operator

I created a react functional component to wrap sections of code based on a predicate (instead of using ternary within JSX).

So, the component looks like this:

```
const PredicateWrapper = ({ children, iff, otherwise }) => (
    iff ? children : (otherwise || null)
);
```

And can be used like this:

```
<PredicateWrapper iff={students}>
   {students.map(student => <Student />)}
</PredicateWrapper>
```

The issue is that this throws an error "cannot read property map of null" if `students` is null. If I replace the `students.map` with some text, the text does not render, proving the wrapper is working, however, the point of the wrapper is to deal with cases where `students` is null, and I would expect it not to "enter" inside the wrapper.

How can I achieve something like this that allows for the inner code to not evaluate and throw runtime errors if `iff` is falsy?

Answer (score 0):

Really interesting question!

I could be woefully wrong here but I think it's because `students.map(student => <Student />` is still part of your parent component's render tree. So when React tries to build the parent component's tree, it's trying to execute that line which throws an error.

`PredicateWrapper` is mounted and resolved when the child components are recursed upon, which is when the `iff` would kick in - but that's on the second iteration.

For eg, if I do this, I don't get the error

```
const Child = ({ students }) => {
  return students.map(student => <Student />);
};


<PredicateWrapper iff={students}>
  <Child students={students} />
</PredicateWrapper>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at how the JSX will be compiled to JavaScript with the [online Babel compiler](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=FAYw9gdgzgLgBABQE4FMAmBLEBDGKDqS2ADsSknALxwAUA3nCABYYA2aqEANHBgGZ8eYGE3IB3DFBRwAvgEoqAPlrA4a3gLgB-Ri3ac4ALlrDRSCVLgAfK3AgBXVqznA5AbmChIsOLHtoUCBgoKjtHVg8vaHgAQVJQmgVKZRpVOAAeZHQsXAIiUnINPko6PwCgqBlFNPVSmH9A4IA6AFsSGjLGpQyAZXry-AB6RTkZNPTBrMwcPEISMiRq908gA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=react&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.10.2&externalPlugins=):

```
const PredicateWrapper = ({ children, iff, otherwise }) =>
  iff ? children : otherwise || null;

const students = null;

const App = () =>
  React.createElement(
    PredicateWrapper,
    {
      iff: students,
    },
    students.map((student) => React.createElement(Student, null))
  );
```

Now you can see `students.map` will be executed and cause the error "Cannot read property map of null"

One possible implementation to achieve your goal is to use **render props**:

> The term “render prop” refers to a technique for sharing code between
>   React components using a prop whose value is a function.

```
const PredicateWrapper = ({ render, iff, otherwise = () => null }) =>
  iff ? render() : otherwise();

const StudentA = () => <span></span>;
const StudentB = () => <span></span>;

const students = [StudentA, StudentB];
//const students = null;

function App() {
  return (
    <PredicateWrapper
      iff={students}
      render={() => students.map(Student => <Student />)}
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-predicate-functional-component]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I'm not sure I like the proposed solution, though, since the  render contents might be very large. If I'm already wrapping it withing curly brackets, I can use ternary instead